# How to create a java method on a base class that calls other methods?

Tags: java, extends, radix

I'm trying to build a base class with a method that needs to call a private method before and after performing the actual logic.

```
public abstract class Base {

  public Base() {}

  private void before() {
    // doSomething
  }

  private void after() {
    // doSomething
  }

  public void actual(Object object) {
    before();
    // doSomething
    after();
  }

}

public class SomeClass extends Base {

  public SomeClass() {}

  public void actual(Object object) {
    // actual code that needs to be executed between before and after methods.
  }

}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Add a protected abstract method that is called in place of `// doSomething` (in `actual`) and consider making `actual` final.

Comment: How about making the methods `protected` instead of `private` in the base class? Do that only if you want to inherit those methods (implementation stays as it is in the `Base`). Alternatively, you can do what @Slaw stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another method that can be overridden and implemented instead of overriding `actual` directly.

E.g.

```
public void actual(Object object) {
    before();
    doActual(object);
    after();
}

protected abstract void doActual(Object object);
```

You could make the `actual()` method `final` if you want to ensure that nobody overrides it by mistake.

Comment: If before() and after() MUST be called for some reason, actual should be private so a subclass cannot override it.

Comment: @jalynn2 The `actual` method is the public API that allows users to indirectly invoke `doActual`, making it private would defeat the purpose. Perhaps you meant to suggest making it final?

Comment: It's a good point about perhaps not wanting classes to be able to override it. A solution would be to make it `final`. I've edited the post to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the method as abstract e.g.

```
protected abstract void actual(Object object);
```

and create another public method which is going to be called

```
public void init(Object object){
  before();
  actual(object);
  after();
}
```